# Limit characters user can enter in input in django view OR html?

Tags: html, django, input, limit, restriction

I had various occasions where I wanted to but couldn’t limit characters user types in html input. For example what would I do if I would only want numbers and letters? No other like £-“<#>{[. And what would I do if I would want them to only enter uppercase letters?
Thanks for help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you can do this, through Django Form validation, HTML attributes or Javascript.

#### Django Validation + HTML attributes

```py
class TheForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModuleChoice
        fields = (
            'text',
            )

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(TheForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # HTML attributes:
            # Max Length, user physically couldn't type more than 35
            # some fields also can have the `pattern` attribute which allows you to have REGEX
        self.fields['text'].widget.attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'maxlength': '35'}


    def is_valid(self):
        valid = super(TheForm, self).is_valid()
        if not self.cleaned_data.get('text'):
            self.add_error('text', 'text needs a Value')
            valid = False

        invalidChars = [ '£', '-', '“', '<', '#', '>', '{', '[' ]
        if any([c in self.cleaned_data.get('text') for c in invalidChars]):
            # error ( {field}, {msg} )
            self.add_error('text', 'These £-“<#>{[ characters are Illegal.')
            valid = False

        if self.cleaned_data.get('text').islower():
            self.add_error('text', 'All Letters Must be all Upper Case.')
            valid = False

        # you could also do Regex:
        import re
        if re.findall('^Nealium.*Uncool$', self.cleaned_data.get('text')):
            self.add_error('text', 'You cannot say Nealium is Uncool.')
            valid = False

        # the sky is the limit..
        if The.objects.filter(text=self.cleaned_data.get('text')).count():
            self.add_error('text', 'Duplicate Text.')
            valid = False

        return valid
```

you would then put, *below*, in your template and if you re-render the page with the invalid form it'll show them.

```html
{% if form.errors %}{{form.errors}}{% endif %}
```

Or you can use, *below*, so access your errors in the template

```py
print(form.errors)
print(form.errors.as_data())
```

Doing it through Javascript is very Similar to the is_valid() in Django Forms, you'd just override the default form.save event and add a few if statements above submitting it

---

#### Edit

Yes, you could do it in the **View**- Specifically in the POST:

```py
def theview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST'
        valid = True
        text = request.POST.get('text')

        invalidChars = [ '£', '-', '“', '<', '#', '>', '{', '[' ]
        if any([c in text for c in invalidChars]):
            msg = 'These £-“<#>{[ characters are Illegal.'
            valid = False

        # other validation

        if valid:
            The.object.create(text=text)
            render(request, 'success.html')
        # not valid
```

Or you could do it in the **Template** if you're manually rendering the Form fields

```html
<form method="post">
    <input id="id_text" name="text" maxlength="35"/>
    <submit>Submit</submit>
</form>
```

---

**but** if you are rendering your forms in the **Template** like:

```html
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

or:

```html
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.text }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and your **View** looks like:

```py
def theview(request):
    form = TheForm()

    if request.method == 'POST'
        form = TheForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            render(request, 'success.html')
      
    data = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'form.html', data)
```

You might as well do it through the **Form** object (which was the 1st example)

Comment: Could I do similar in view? or in html? i heared something about patterns…

Comment: If you want to be _sure_ no unwanted input gets through, the javascript solution is not good enough; you absolutely have to check it on the server side, because a user could create a request by some other means than your javascript code.

Comment: Opps, looks like I forgot submit my comment. Yes, you could to something similar in the View or HTML. I've added an edit that would show both. Django is sort of built around forms, so I might be a better idea to do it all through them- but I myself have done validation in Views/Html/JS when it's a more complicated page